# Error when get connection from SQLServerDataSource

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a local SQL Server instance. If I try to connect with Management Studio (SQL Server authentication, with username and password) everything works fine.

However, when I try to create a connection from a Spring Boot application I get some errors.

This is the code for the Datasource (dbUsername and dbpassword are correct)

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLServerException {
    SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
    ds.setUser(dbUsername);
    ds.setPassword(dbPassword);
    ds.setServerName("localhost");
    ds.setPortNumber(1433);
    ds.setDatabaseName("mydb");
    return ds;
}
```

When I try retrieve a connection with

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

I get this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user
> '"sa"'.

If I add `ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true);` I have a different error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not
> configured for integrated authentication.

This is the JDBC driver that I'm using:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you even using `SQLServerDataSource`? In a web application it is better to use a data source that provides connection pooling. Spring Boot out of the box uses HikariCP for that, where you can define the datasource entirely in the config, without having to define a bean like this.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel thank you for your comment; could you give me a link where I can find an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: You could start with [Spring Boot Features: Working with SQL Databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I encourage you to connect your DB by setting the configuration in the application.yaml file. It is in `src/resources/application.yaml`

1. Create an `application.yaml` file (if it does not exist already).
2. Copy this content:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    URL: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/mydb?reconnect=true
    username: username
    password: password
```

3. Replace the username and password with yours.
4. Delete the bean you've created.
5. Good luck!

Comment: Given the OP is using SQL Server, they would also need to replace the url.

Comment: URLs for SQL server start with `jdbc:sqlserver:` and are governed by the syntax documented on [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks again! I looked at the docs of MSSQL :)

Comment: I solve using the application.properties file as suggested; I add these 3 entries spring.datasource.url,  spring.datasource.username,spring.datasource.password and spring created a dataSource bean for me.